# Cannot POST PHP file for contact form?

Tags: php, html, forms

So I have published my website, but am making minor improvements to it as time progresses. Just a note: I am impatient and this is making me want to obliterate myself. Help!

So the question is the title. I have a contact form on my website which uses HTML and PHP.

Here is the form on HTML:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
        Name<br>
        <input type="text" name="cf_name"><br>
        E-Mail<br>
        <input type="text" name="cf_email"><br>
        Message<br>
        <textarea name="cf_message"></textarea></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear">
            </form>
```

And here is the PHP for it:

```
 <?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'amir@arshak.co.uk';
$subject = 'ALERT! Somebody has viewed your website!'.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thanks. I have recieved your message. I may reply to the given e-mail.');
        window.location = 'contact.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Sorry, your message failed to send. Send an email to amir@arshak.co.uk');
        window.location = 'contact.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with the code!

Comment: Please explain what the actual problem is that you are experiencing

Comment: When I use the live preview feature on Brackets, it says: Cannot POST (file directory here)
But, when I save it and open it in regular chrome, it just posts the actual php file.

This happens when I have filled out the information in the form and click the submit button.

Comment: If you mean that when you submit the form in Chrome the actual PHP code shows in your browser then this means that your server is misconfigured and is not processing the PHP code and is just outputting it as text.

Comment: OK. Thank you. But how to fix it the way you are saying it?

Comment: It's not a code issue but a server configuration issue and without access to your environment it is impossible to suggest a fix. If the code is deployed on a remote server and you are having this issue then you should speak to your hosting provider. If this problem is happening on your computer then you need to ensure you have PHP installed and setup correctly.

Comment: Figured the solution! It sounds a bit silly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that the email won't send...

You are allowing the from and reply-to addresses to be set to whatever is entered into the form.

A lot of mail servers will only allow an email to be sent where the from address matches the email address used to authenticate with the server.

This could possibly be causing your issue although it's hard to say without much more information.

Comment: Well yes, and yes. The e-mail won't send even when I have tried it with an authentic e-mail, and yes, thanks for the idea.